# How to get controls inside Pivot.ItemTemplate in Pivot in UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I have the following code:

```
 <ScrollViewer x:Name="swipeBetweenPages" Grid.Row="1">
                    <Pivot DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}" x:Name="pivot" Margin="0,-45,0,0" 
                                     HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource headerTest}" 
                           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource pivotTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}" SelectionChanged="pivot_SelectionChanged">
                    </Pivot>
                </ScrollViewer>

<Page.Resources>
        <ViewModels:ArticleViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="headerTest">
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="pivotTemplate">
            <StackPanel Margin="-15 0 -15 0">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <ImageBrush AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center" ImageSource="Assets/PlaceHolder.jpg"></ImageBrush>
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <Image q42controls:ImageExtensions.CacheUri="{Binding ImageURL}" Tag="{Binding ImageURL}" Tapped="ImageView"></Image>
                </Grid>
                <StackPanel Background="White">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="HeadLine" Text="{Binding HeadLine}"  
                                               Margin="10 5 0 -5" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                               FontSize="20" Foreground="Black"
                                               FontFamily="{StaticResource HeadlineCommonFamiy}"
                                               Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="GroupTwo" Height="63"
                                               FontWeight="Bold" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Abstract}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="15" FontStyle="Italic"
                                   Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="GroupTwo" Margin="10 5 0 10"
                                           FontFamily="{StaticResource AbstractCommonFamily}"/>                   
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel x:Name="descriptionSP" Background="White">
                <RichTextBlock IsTextSelectionEnabled="False" x:Name="richTextBlock" 
                               local:Properties.Html="{Binding ArticleDetail}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="GroupTwo" Margin="10 5 0 10"
                                       FontFamily="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}">
                </RichTextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>
```

How to get the RichTextBlock control inside the stackpanel?

Now, I am trying with the following code in the C# end:

```
private T FindElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);
            if (count == 0) return null;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                    return (T)child;
                else
                {
                    var result = FindElementInVisualTree<T>(child);
                    if (result != null)
                        return result;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

RichTextBlock richTextBlock = new RichTextBlock();
            StackPanel rootStackPanel = new StackPanel();
            StackPanel childStackPanel = new StackPanel();

    PivotItem item = (sender as Pivot).ContainerFromItem((sender as Pivot).SelectedItem) as PivotItem;
            rootStackPanel = item.ContentTemplate.LoadContent() as StackPanel;
            childStackPanel = rootStackPanel.FindName("descriptionSP") as StackPanel;
            richTextBlock = rootStackPanel.FindName("richTextBlock") as RichTextBlock;

 Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
            Run run = new Run();

            // Customize some properties on the RichTextBlock.
            richTextBlock.IsTextSelectionEnabled = true;
            richTextBlock.SelectionHighlightColor = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Pink);
            richTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Blue);
            richTextBlock.FontWeight = Windows.UI.Text.FontWeights.Light;
            richTextBlock.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
            richTextBlock.FontStyle = Windows.UI.Text.FontStyle.Italic;
            richTextBlock.FontSize = 50;
            //run.Text = "This is some sample text to demonstrate some properties.";

            //Add the Run to the Paragraph, the Paragraph to the RichTextBlock.
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(run);
            richTextBlock.Blocks.Add(paragraph);

            // Add the RichTextBlock to the visual tree (assumes stackPanel is decalred in XAML).
            //childStackPanel.Children.Add(richTextBlock);
            //rootStackPanel.Children.Add(richTextBlock);
```

But I am not able to get the control `RichTextBlock`. I am getting a `null` value.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ContentTemplate` of `PivotItem` to get the template of `PivotItem` for example like this:

```
PivotItem item = (sender as Pivot).ContainerFromItem((sender as Pivot).SelectedItem) as PivotItem;
var rootStackPanel = item.ContentTemplate.LoadContent() as StackPanel;
var richtb = rootStackPanel.FindName("richtb") as RichTextBlock;
```

And I firstly gave a name to the `RichTextBlock` as "richtb".

Comment: thanks @grace, i am able to get the richtextblock control. I have question. I am trying to set font size to richtextblock as richtb.Fontsize=20 in the c# end. But it is not affecting. But if i am setting from xaml it's working fine. Is it correct way to set the font size in the back end or is there any other way to set? Please help me. Thanks

Comment: @BhanuprakashMankala, for `RichTextBlock`, we need to access to the `Block` of this control in the code behind, the contents are in blocks, you can refer to the samples in [RichTextBlock class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblock.aspx).

Comment: As in my XAML, i am binding the data from "local:Properties.Html", and i am not using Paragraph properties. Is it possible to get the blocks using my code?

Comment: @BhanuprakashMankala, it's possible, you can have a try.

Comment: Hi @grace, i have edited my question. Please look into it. And i am trying to get the blocks, trying to customize richtextblock. But, it is not working. Is it the right way? Please help me.

Comment: @BhanuprakashMankala, instead of editing this question, could you please open a new thread?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120481/discussion-between-bhanuprakash-mankala-and-grace-feng-msft).

Comment: Hi @grace, please look into the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845441/set-font-size-to-richtexblock-in-uwp-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided searches the tree for the first matching control of the given type. This means, that what you get in return is the first `StackPanel` in the XAML definition, but the `RichTextBlock` in the second one.

Why don't you directly do this, instead of searching for the `StackPanel`:

```
var richTextBlock = FindElementInVisualTree<RichTextBlock>(item);
```

This will return the `RichTextBlock` directly, because the `FindElementInVisualTree` method is searching down the tree recursively.

Comment: i have tried that also, in that case also i am getting null value.

Comment: Can you check if the `item` variable is not null?

Comment: i have tried with the above answer by Grace, and i am able to get the richtextblock control.